# Static and dynamic methods within the same php class

Tags: php

assume i have a class like so:

```
class ClassA{

    var $var = 'a1';
    static $static_var = 'a2';

    function get(){
        return $this->var;
    }

    static function get_static(){
        return self::$static_var;
    }

}
```

What happens in memory when I call this:

```
$class = new ClassA();
echo $class->get();
```

And also what happens when I call this:

```
echo ClassA::get_static();
```

When I create an instance of ClassA, what happens to the static members of the class? Does it take up more memory? Does it ignore the static members?

I want to keep a bunch of static functions within `ClassA` but I also want to create instances of ClassA. Should I separate static members from dynamic members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to keep a bunch of static functions within ClassA but I also want to create instances of ClassA. Should I separate static members from dynamic members?

Answer: Static class members consuming memory once per *per class*. Regular class members consuming memory once *per instance*

Comment: so when i create 1000 instances of ClassA i have 1000 copies of variable `$var` and just 1 copy of `$static_var`?

Comment: i just wanted to know if the static members influenced how much memory an instance of a class takes up. i guess this answers my question